# Trouble deserializing a document containing xsi:type attributes

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xsd, xsitype

When parsing XML file I have error in `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` :
`Namespace prefix \"java\" not defined`

my XML http://www.virtualdtm.ru/files/serverReplays/rFactorHotlapsData.xml

my code

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootDB));
var reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/xml/rFactorHotlapsData.xml")));
var rFactorHotLapsData = (rootDB)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

my class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Этот код создан программой.
//     Исполняемая версия:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Изменения в этом файле могут привести к неправильной работе и будут потеряны в случае
//     повторной генерации кода.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace net.vmso.cpanel.Models.rFactorHotLaps
{
}

// 
// Этот исходный код был создан с помощью xsd, версия=4.0.30319.17929.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class rootDB {

    private rootDBListOfCategory[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("listOfCategory", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public rootDBListOfCategory[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rootDBListOfCategory {

    private string categoryNameField;

    private rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrack[] listOfTrackField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string categoryName {
        get {
            return this.categoryNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.categoryNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("listOfTrack", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrack[] listOfTrack {
        get {
            return this.listOfTrackField;
        }
        set {
            this.listOfTrackField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrack {

    private string trackNameField;

    private rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackSlowestLapRecord[] slowestLapRecordField;

    private rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackListOfLapRecord[] listOfLapRecordField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string trackName {
        get {
            return this.trackNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.trackNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("slowestLapRecord", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackSlowestLapRecord[] slowestLapRecord {
        get {
            return this.slowestLapRecordField;
        }
        set {
            this.slowestLapRecordField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("listOfLapRecord", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackListOfLapRecord[] listOfLapRecord {
        get {
            return this.listOfLapRecordField;
        }
        set {
            this.listOfLapRecordField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackSlowestLapRecord {

    private string driverNameField;

    private string sessionNameField;

    private string dateField;

    private string vehicleModNameField;

    private string vehicleNameField;

    private string vehicleCategoryField;

    private string lapTimeField;

    private string lastLapTimeField;

    private string rankField;

    private string sessionIdField;

    private string lapCountField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string driverName {
        get {
            return this.driverNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.driverNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string sessionName {
        get {
            return this.sessionNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.sessionNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string date {
        get {
            return this.dateField;
        }
        set {
            this.dateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string vehicleModName {
        get {
            return this.vehicleModNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.vehicleModNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string vehicleName {
        get {
            return this.vehicleNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.vehicleNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string vehicleCategory {
        get {
            return this.vehicleCategoryField;
        }
        set {
            this.vehicleCategoryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lapTime {
        get {
            return this.lapTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.lapTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lastLapTime {
        get {
            return this.lastLapTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.lastLapTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string rank {
        get {
            return this.rankField;
        }
        set {
            this.rankField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string sessionId {
        get {
            return this.sessionIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.sessionIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lapCount {
        get {
            return this.lapCountField;
        }
        set {
            this.lapCountField = value;
        }
    }
}

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    public partial class rootDBListOfCategoryListOfTrackListOfLapRecord {

        private string driverNameField;

        private string sessionNameField;

        private string dateField;

        private string vehicleModNameField;

        private string vehicleNameField;

        private string vehicleCategoryField;

        private string lapTimeField;

        private string lastLapTimeField;

        private string rankField;

        private string sessionIdField;

        private string lapCountField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string driverName {
            get {
                return this.driverNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.driverNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string sessionName {
            get {
                return this.sessionNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.sessionNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string date {
            get {
                return this.dateField;
            }
            set {
                this.dateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string vehicleModName {
            get {
                return this.vehicleModNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.vehicleModNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string vehicleName {
            get {
                return this.vehicleNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.vehicleNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string vehicleCategory {
            get {
                return this.vehicleCategoryField;
            }
            set {
                this.vehicleCategoryField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string lapTime {
            get {
                return this.lapTimeField;
            }
            set {
                this.lapTimeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string lastLapTime {
            get {
                return this.lastLapTimeField;
            }
            set {
                this.lastLapTimeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string rank {
            get {
                return this.rankField;
            }
            set {
                this.rankField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string sessionId {
            get {
                return this.sessionIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.sessionIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string lapCount {
            get {
                return this.lapCountField;
            }
            set {
                this.lapCountField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

[1]:

Comment: The xsi:type is set to java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Category. the prefix java of this type is not linked to a namespace.

Comment: flup, thanks for comment, Me don't lack the knowledge to deal with the problem itself.

Comment: Are you able to alter the document?

Comment: This XML document is generated by third-party software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java namespace prefix is not defined, but it is used in the xsi:type attributes of your .xml document. If you add an attribute that defines it it to the root of your document, the error will go away.

```
<rootDB xmlns:java="http://tempuri3.org">
```

As we later found out, on top of this the xsi:type is messing up the generation of the classes. Badly.

**Using XmlSerializer**

```
<listOfTrack xsi:type="java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Track">
```

The name of the element is `listOfTrack`, in the default namespace. Its type however is `com.prorfactor.top100.database.Track` in the namespace the java prefix is referring to. This happens because the `xsi:type` attribute changes it. xsd.exe can deal with this, but it needs a little help.

The way I got it to work is to create two `.xsd`s. One for the java namespace and the other for the namespace of the document. They import each other.
As an example I'll show the bit that describes the start of the document where the names and types hop around a lot.

```
<rootDB xmlns="http://tempuri2.org"
        xmlns:java="http://tempuri3.org">
  <listOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Category">
    <listOfTrack xsi:type="java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Track">
```

For the default namespace, which I called `http://tempuri2.org`, the schema has to list the names of the elements, because they are in the default namespace:

```
  <xs:element name="rootDB" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="listOfCategory" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="listOfCategory"
              type="java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Category">
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="listOfTrack"
              type="java:com.prorfactor.top100.database.Track">
  </xs:element>
```

The schema for the java namespace, which I called `http://tempuri3.org` lists the complextypes that are assigned to the elements using xsi:type:

```
  <xs:complexType name="com.prorfactor.top100.database.Category"
        xmlns:orig="http://tempuri2.org">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="orig:listOfTrack" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="orig:categoryName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="com.prorfactor.top100.database.Track"
        xmlns:orig="http://tempuri2.org">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="orig:slowestLapRecord" />
      <xs:element ref="orig:listOfLapRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element ref="orig:trackName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

These two `.xsd`s I compiled and the generated classes manage to deserialize the .xml file.

IF I manually add the java namespace, plus specify the default namespace to the .xml file

So, to be honest, I think you're better off using LINQ to XML:

**Using LINQ to XML**

```
XDocument xElement = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/xml/rFactorHotlapsData.xml")));

// just some selects to show how you select them
var cats = from cat in xElement.Descendants("listOfCategory")
           select new
           {
              Name = cat.Descendants("categoryName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
              Track = from track in cat.Descendants("listOfTrack")
                      select new 
                      {
                         Name = track.Descendants("trackName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                         LapRecord = from record in cat.Descendants("listOfLapRecord")
                                     select new
                                     {
                                        driverName = record.Descendants("driverName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                        sessionName = record.Descendants("sessionName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                        date = record.Descendants("date").FirstOrDefault().Value
                                     }
                       }
           };

// And a demo of how to iterate over the result of the select
foreach (var category in cats)
{
   Console.WriteLine(category.Name);
   foreach (var track in category.Track)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("  " + track.Name);
      foreach (var lapRecord in track.LapRecord)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("      " + lapRecord.driverName);
         Console.WriteLine("      " + lapRecord.sessionName);
         Console.WriteLine("      " + lapRecord.date);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: new error:
Указанный тип не был распознан: имя="com.prorfactor.top100.database.Category", пространство имен="http://java.oracle.com/", в <listOfCategory xmlns=''>.

Comment: Your deserializer does not use the java namespace either. The root element also needs to be in the namespace. How did you generate the Deserializer? From an XSD?

Comment: You can manually add the same (made up) namespace to the annotations of the root element: `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://java.oracle.com", IsNullable=false)]` but maybe it's better to take a look at the .xsd too then

Comment: yes, i generate XSD from XML and generate Class File from XSD over XSD.exe tool

Comment: I do not understand what I do. This is bad.

Comment: Can you add a link to the .XSD?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23059/discussion-between-roman-barulin-and-flup)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understood what to do. As soon as I create working code will close the issue.